# Including or excluding range attribute in dynamically generate form field

Tags: coldfusion

I am using a query to dynamically create form fields, not all fields use the range attribute.
When using the `cfif` statement to include or exclude the range attribute I get an error:

See code below:

```
<cfoutput>
    <input type="hidden" name="question_ids" id="question_ids" value="#valueList(rsQuestions.question_id)#">
</cfoutput>
<cfoutput query="rsQuestions" group="modid">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="4" cellspacing="4" bgcolor="##0E777A" >
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><span class="style1">#rsQuestions.ModName#</span></td>
    </tr>
    <cfoutput>
    <tr>
        <td width="700" bgcolor="##FFFFFF">#rsQuestions.question#</td>
        <td width="200" bgcolor="##FFFFFF">
        <cfif rsQuestions.question_type_id eq 1>
            <cfinput type="text" name="answer_#rsQuestions.question_id#" 
                message="#rsQuestions.Message#" 
                tooltip="#rsQuestions.Tooltip#" 
                validate="#rsQuestions.Validate#"
                <cfif #rsQuestions.Range# neq "">
                    range = "#rsQuestions.Range#"
                </cfif>
                required="#rsQuestions.mandatory#"
                size="#rsQuestions.Size#">
        <cfelseif rsQuestions.question_type_id eq 2>    
            <cfquery name="rsOptions" datasource="dsTest">
            SELECT     option_id, [option], question_id
            FROM         questionnaire_question_options
            WHERE     (question_id = #rsQuestions.question_id#)
            </cfquery>
            <cfselect enabled="yes" 
                name="answer_#rsQuestions.question_id#" 
                multiple="no" 
                query="rsOptions" 
                value="option" 
                display="option">
            </cfselect>   
        </cfif>   
        </td>
    </tr>
    </cfoutput>
    </table>
</cfoutput>
```

How can I structure the above statement to include or exclude the 'range' attribute?

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also, please check out this blog entry about when to use pound signs - http://cfmlblog.adamcameron.me/2013/09/when-to-use-pound-signs.html

Comment: Coldfusion doesn't except the cfif tag within the cfinput attribute tag.

Answer (score 1):

As user8675309 (Jenny?) mentioned, you cannot nest `<cfif>` tags inside another CF tag. So you need to separate those statements out. Here is one way you could do that:

```
....
<cfif rsQuestions.question_type_id eq 1>
    <cfif rsQuestions.Range neq "">
        <cfinput type="text" name="answer_#rsQuestions.question_id#" 
            message="#rsQuestions.Message#" 
            tooltip="#rsQuestions.Tooltip#" 
            validate="#rsQuestions.Validate#"
            range="#rsQuestions.Range#"
            required="#rsQuestions.mandatory#"
            size="#rsQuestions.Size#">
    <cfelse>
        <cfinput type="text" name="answer_#rsQuestions.question_id#" 
            message="#rsQuestions.Message#" 
            tooltip="#rsQuestions.Tooltip#" 
            validate="#rsQuestions.Validate#"
            required="#rsQuestions.mandatory#"
            size="#rsQuestions.Size#">
    </cfif>
<cfelseif rsQuestions.question_type_id eq 2>    
....
```

Comment: @Johan - if this worked for you then please accept it as the answer so that others can find it more easily.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, you can't nest a `cfif` (or any CF tag) inside another CF tag.

One thing you can do if you really need dynamic attributes is to use the "attributeCollection" attribute.
(ColdFusion 8 or higher.)

Something like:

```
<cfset inputAttr=structNew()>
<cfset inputAttr.type="text">
<cfset inputAttr.name="answer_#rsQuestions.question_id#">
<cfset inputAttr.message="#rsQuestions.Message#">
<cfset inputAttr.tooltip="#rsQuestions.Tooltip#">
<cfset inputAttr.validate="#rsQuestions.Validate#">
<cfif rsQuestions.Range neq "">
  <cfset inputAttr.range = "#rsQuestions.Range#">
</cfif>
<cfset inputAttr.required="#rsQuestions.mandatory#">
<cfset inputAttr.size="#rsQuestions.Size#">

<cfinput attributecollection="#inputAttr#">
```

Comment: When I use the above code I get the error - "attribute validation error for tag cfinput: The tag requires the attribute: NAME

Comment: The version is Coldfusion MX7

Comment: That'd be the problem then. AttributeCollection was added in CF 8. You should include the version you're working with in your question.

Comment: Basically you'll need a `cfif`/`cfelse` wrapped around two different `cfinput`. (As [Miguel-F has done](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18916701/21960).)